# Reading memory that was not allocated

Tags: windows, visual-c++, heap-memory, heap-corruption

I have a class object that creates a magic word in its constructor which I check to make sure I really constructed the object. Very rarely when I dont create the object, memory is not allocated and I crash when I try to access the member. Is it fine if I capture the SIGSEGV generated at this time and I return false, so that I dont allow my program to continue using the object? Would I have corrupted the memory? I would try to access the member which would throw a SIGSEGV, I capture it and tell me program not to proceed with this object. What are the problems with this? Why can I do it? or Why shouldn't I do this? I WOULD NOT BE WRITING ANYTHING, just a try to read.

TIA!

Comment: XY problem, I think.  Why exactly don't you know whether the object has been created or not?  You must have a pointer to the object, what is that set to if there isn't an object to point to?

Comment: This is not a solution I am thinking of, it is a very old code base and has solved the problem this way. So just want to make sure this is alright. Also, why I would not know if I allocated memory is, I am just making sure that memory has been allocated. I know, but I want to be sure.

Comment: If you get SIGSEV when you try to read, nothing is corrupted except possibly your program state if you don't capture the error. You're not going to harm anything external if you catch the error and stop trying to read. This isn't particularly good practice, though, even if you're just reading. If you don't know what the pointer is referencing, then you have no idea if what you're reading is what you meant to read. You should always know what you're referencing before you try to read.

Comment: @JimMischel thanks for your reply! So, I would be safe both externally and within the program if I try to read and catch SIGSEGV if it was thrown and stop and not read but continue doing other stuff right?

Comment: Yes. Try to read, catch the exception, and move on.

Comment: @JimMischelThanks!

Comment: If you've allocated the memory and get an access violation anyway, there's a severe bug in your program.  You *might* want to catch the exception in order to write a crash log or emergency autosave, but catching it and carrying on as if nothing is wrong is bad practice, because it means you won't find out about the bug.  See also [IsBadXxxPtr should really be called CrashProgramRandomly](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060927-07/?p=29563).